# How to connect from MQTT javascript client to Mosquitto Server?

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto

error log in console browser :
 "WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

my code .js to connect mosquitto server:

```
var options = {
            clientId: 'web-client',
            connectTimeout: 5000,
            hostname: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 1883,
            path: '/mqtt'
        };

var client = mqtt.connect(options);
```

- use library mqtt-2.9.0.js
- use mosquitto v1.5.4 windows10

=========================================

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Mosquitto listens on port 1883 and accepts connections using native MQTT

If you want to connect with MQTT over Websockets you need to configure Mosquitto to listen on a different port and specify to use the `websockets` transport.

You can add the following to your mosquitto.conf:

```
listener 8883
protocol websockets
```

This will cause mosquitto to listen on port 8883 for MQTT over Websockets conections.

You can then modify your code as follows:

```
 var options = {
   clientId: 'web-client',
   connectTimeout: 5000,
   hostname: '127.0.0.1',
   port: 8883,
     path: '/mqtt'
   };

var client = mqtt.connect(options);
```

It's also worth pointing out that your clientId needs to be unique for EVERY client that connects, so you will need to make it dynamic if you are going to load the page more than once at a time.

Comment: i think so.. but when i edit mosquitto.conf to added
listener 8883
protocol websockets

its not work. I checked in "netsat -an" and did not read port 8883. it should be read

Comment: are you sure just add listener 8883
protocol websockets ?

Comment: You need to make sure that mosquitto is using the config file. How are you starting mosquitto?

Comment: C:\Program Files\mosquitto2>mosquitto -v  just like that

Comment: OMGGGGGGG ITS WORK IF I USE mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf

Answer (score 1):

While 1883 is the usual port for vanilla MQTT connection - the usual default for websockets is port 8883. Have you tried port 8883?

Durr edited my typo 8888 to 8883

Comment: While there is no standard port for MQTT over websockets the accepted normal is 8883 (though in production you should probably use port 80 or 443 to match http/https)